# Add MySQL column comment as a metadata to Avro schema through the Debezium connector

Tags: debezium

Kafka Connect is used through the Confluent platform and `io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector` is used as the Debezium connector.

In my case, MySQL table includes columns with sensitive data and these columns must be tagged as sensitive for further use.

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM astronauts;
+---------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+------------------+
| Field   | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment          |
+---------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+------------------+
| orderid | int          | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |                  |
| name    | varchar(100) | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references | sensitive column |
+---------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+------------------+
```

Notice MySQL comment for the `name` column.

Based on this table, I would like to have this Avro schema in the Schema registry:

```
{
  "connect.name": "dbserver1.inventory.astronauts.Envelope",
  "connect.version": 1,
  "fields": [
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "before",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "connect.name": "dbserver1.inventory.astronauts.Value",
          "fields": [
            {
              "default": null,
              "name": "orderid",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "int"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "name",
              "type": {
                "MY_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE": "sensitive column",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          ],
          "name": "Value",
          "type": "record"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "after",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "Value"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "source",
      "type": {
        "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "version",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "connector",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "ts_ms",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "default": "false",
            "name": "snapshot",
            "type": [
              {
                "connect.default": "false",
                "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
                "connect.parameters": {
                  "allowed": "true,last,false,incremental"
                },
                "connect.version": 1,
                "type": "string"
              },
              "null"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "db",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "default": null,
            "name": "sequence",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ]
          },
          {
            "default": null,
            "name": "table",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "server_id",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "default": null,
            "name": "gtid",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "file",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "pos",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "name": "row",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "default": null,
            "name": "thread",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "long"
            ]
          },
          {
            "default": null,
            "name": "query",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "name": "Source",
        "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.mysql",
        "type": "record"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "op",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "ts_ms",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "long"
      ]
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "transaction",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "connect.name": "event.block",
          "connect.version": 1,
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "total_order",
              "type": "long"
            },
            {
              "name": "data_collection_order",
              "type": "long"
            }
          ],
          "name": "block",
          "namespace": "event",
          "type": "record"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "name": "Envelope",
  "namespace": "dbserver1.inventory.astronauts",
  "type": "record"
}
```

Notice the custom schema field named `MY_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE`.

[Debezium 2.0](https://debezium.io/releases/2.0/release-notes#release-2.0.0-final) supports `schema doc from column comments` [[DBZ-5489](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-5489)], however, personally I think the `doc` field attribute is not appropriate since:

- any implementation of a schema registry or system that processes the schemas is free to drop those fields when encoding/decoding and its fully spec compliant
- Additionally, the doc field is solely intended to provide information to a user of the schema and is not intended as a form of metadata that downstream programs can rely on

source: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/spec.html#Schema+Resolution

Based on the Avro schema docs, custom attributes for Avro schemas are allowed and these attributes are known as metadata:

> A JSON object, of the form:
>
> {"type": "typeName" ...attributes...}
>
> where typeName is either a primitive or derived type name, as defined below. Attributes not defined in this document are permitted as metadata, but must not affect the format of serialized data.

source: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/spec.html#schemas

I think Debezium [transformations](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/index.html) might be a solution, however, I have the following problems:

1. No idea how to get MySQL column comments in my custom transformation
2. [`org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaBuilder.html) does not allow to add custom attributes, afaik just [`doc`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaBuilder.html#doc-java.lang.String-) and the specific [`field`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaBuilder.html#field-java.lang.String-)

Here are several native transformations for reference: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/